# How to use glDrawTex*

Tags: iphone, image, opengl-es, background

I want to take a .png image and use it as the background for my GLView. I've heard that glDrawTex* was the best way, but I've searched the internet and haven't found a single example of how to use it (at least not one that has worked for me). Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [OES_draw_texture extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt) is a good enough way to draw a background because it may sometimes be a little faster than using geometry, I'd recommend against using it too heavily on the basis that iPhones don't implement it under ES 2 and you don't want to box yourself into a corner.

That being said, something like:

```
int sourceRect[4] = {0, 24, 8, 16};  // we'll use the rectangle from (0, 24) of
                                     // size (8, 16) in the texture or textures
                                     // that are currently active as the
                                     // source graphic...

// ... by saying as much to OpenGL
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, sourceRect);


// we'll then draw that at (x, y), with nominal depth z, so as
// to cover the screen area (width, height)
glDrawTexiOES(x, y, z, width, height);
```

Should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it, but I'm just getting a white screen. In your code, what is 'rect'. Is that supposed to be 'sourceRect'? My texture is a 512x512 pvrtc file. What values should I put in for sourceRect? What values do I put in for glDrawTexiOES? Does this code go in my drawing function? If so, where? My current drawing fuction looks like this:  - (void) Draw { glClear...; glLoadIdentity(); glTranslate( 0, 0, -2.4); glDrawElements...; }

Comment: Nevermind. I had set up my texture incorrectly. Now I have it working.

Comment: Thank you so much, you get some truly gnarly behavior if you try to use glDrawTexiOES() without setting the parameters as you suggest.