# Android opengl es and white textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I'm writing a simple 2D game on Android using OpenGL ES. The problem is that, instead of actual image for some textures only white bar is rendered.

There was neither error during loading textures nor during binding them. All the textures have power of 2 size.

I'm using extension `glDrawTexfOES` to draw textures.
I suspect that I might be running out of GPU memory, but how do I check that? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should enhance the code in two ways:

1. [Set tex parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099703/1262542)
2. [Set crop parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5821745/1262542)

The analogous Android call is

```
((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, new int[]{0,0,100,100},0);
```

Amongst loads of other answers, there is one stating to just setup everything for 2D projection and draw a quad.